# Scan every pixels to get RGB values

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, android-camera, gpu

I want to get RGB values of every pixels while my video streaming is running. I am currently using textureView to display the camera stream. Every time I get a new frame, I scan the frame and see if I have all R G and B value equal to 255. But **the problem is**: It takes more than 20 seconds to scan one frame so it skips 30-40 frames. I want to read pixels without skipping any. 
So, if anyone can let me know if there is an efficient way to do this, I would really appreciate their help.

This is how I'm doing.

```
TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
        openCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    Bitmap bitmap = textureView.getBitmap();

        // Initializing all color values
        int redmax = 0, greenmax = 0, bluemax = 0, redx = 0, bluex = 0, greenx = 0, redy = 0, bluey = 0, greeny = 0;

        int Pixel = bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getWidth();

        ByteBuffer Pixels = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * Pixel);

        for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++) { // Height
            for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++) {    // Width
                GLES20.glReadPixels(x, y, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Pixels);

                byte rValue = Pixels.get(0);
                byte gValue = Pixels.get(1);
                byte bValue = Pixels.get(2);
                byte A = Pixels.get(3);


                if (rValue > redmax) { // This is just to get max red Value in the frame
                    redmax = rValue;
                    redx = x;
                    redy = y;

                }
                if (bValue > bluemax) { // This is just to get max blue Value in the frame
                    bluemax = bValue;
                    bluex = x;
                    bluey = y;
                }

                if (gValue > greenmax) { // This is just to get max green Value in the frame
                    greenmax = gValue;
                    greenx = x;
                    greeny = y;
                }
            }
        }

        Log.i("Picture max red value", "R: " + redmax + " x: " + redx + " y: " + redy);
        Log.i("Picture max green value", "G: " + greenmax + " x: " + greenx + " y: " + greeny);
        Log.i("Picture max blue value", "B: " + bluemax + " x: " + bluex + " y: " + bluey);
        Log.i("Picture x and y value", "XY: " + " x: " + bitmap.getWidth() + " y: " + bitmap.getHeight());

        if ((redmax + bluemax + greenmax) > 760) {
            BitmapUtil.saveBitmap(bitmap, String.format("/sdcard/read_1" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".jpg"));
        } else {
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly your code is working but you need to optimize it. You might want to give a full description on what you are trying to accomplish to get a few ideas but from your code there might be a few pointers. Make sure you create yourself a test scenario with measurable results to see what procedure optimized your code and how much.

A call to `glReadPixels` may be very time consuming so try to reduce it as much as possible. You use it in a for loop which if I am reading this correctly is reading the whole buffer size being offset by `x`, `y` which means it is overflowing next to other things. I believe what you have tried to do is: `GLES20.glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1` which is reading a single pixel at certain position. This should give you quite a performance boost but as mentioned in a comment by @Rabbid76 there is a suspicion you will gain performance by reading the whole buffer and then iterating through pixels.

Some procedures can be offloaded directly to GPU and checking which is the "largest" pixel seems directly like one of those. You could create a FBO (frame buffer object) and keep redrawing the same texture to a buffer that is half the size in each dimension using shaders to preserve the larger values. This at the end would have you a buffer with a single pixel that contains your value but the problem is you lost the position of that pixel (where it originally was).

To explain a bit the procedure of redrawing a texture imagine you have a 2x2 texture that will be redrawn to 1x1 buffer. Fragment shader would fetch 4 nearest pixels and output the one that is largest as in:

```
gl_fragColor = vec4(max(t1.r, max(t2.r, max(t3.r, t4.r))), max(t1.g, max(t2.r, max(t3.g, ...
```

where `tN` are samples at `(0.25, 0.25)`, `(0.75, 0.25)`, `(0.25, 0.75)`, `(0.75, 0.75)`.

This would execute for only a single fragment but a previous call would be with the same shader redrawing 4x4 texture to 2x2 buffer having 4 fragments. The same 16x16 redrawn to 4x4... So all you really needed to do is convert those constants in the shader to use uniforms and compute them.

You should be able to even to put this work on a separate thread and skip frames if that is allowed and needed when it is too expensive. The video should then still play without interruptions.

Comment: Hey @Matic  Can you explain little bit more on GPU use. I am new to this, so I need help

Comment: @Daniel This might be a lot to begin with. I guess I would start with FBO; create a new frame buffer and a texture with any size. Then bind this buffer and draw to it as you did before to your main buffer. Then on every frame once drawn to FBO bind main buffer and the texture that was attached to the FBO and redraw this one to (now bound) main buffer. Use some test shader like grayscale when drawing to FBO just to test the result.

Comment: @Daniel After this FBO is working you should start with downsizing. Find the first POT (power of two) size of texture and use that one as initial FBO texture. So for instance 600x400 would result in 1024x512 texture. Attach this texture to your FBO and use the viewport you need to draw your texture to it (600x400) in this case. Now create yet another FBO with the texture of same size now redraw the thing a few times from one buffer to another while downsizing the viewport by half each time... Let me explain...

Comment: @Daniel The first FBO (will call A) now has a 600x400 texture on it drawn but is 1024x512 in its own size. Now bind the second FBO (B) and set the viewport to half the size now 512x256 and draw the texture from A on it. Then draw back to A using texture from B again downsizing to 256x128. Then again swap drawing A texture to B using 128x64. Should be enough for now. Now try to draw this back on your main frame buffer to see the result. Use texture coordinates so only the inner texture is displayed `(0,(128/1024)*(600/1024)), (0,(64/512)*(400/512))` must result in now same video but low quality

Comment: @Daniel if you get this result you are very close to result now... Adjust your shaders so that you will output the largest value of the 4 nearby pixels from your source texture (What I have described in the answer already). Make sure to use `nearest` setting on textures so no interpolation is done for you. Now instead of redrawing your texture from A to B and back N times do it until the result is 1x1 texture. At this point simply bind the buffer you have just drawn to and read the first pixel (at 0, 0) which should now be your result. Don't forget to still draw the original video.